# jQuery onclick have to click twice for modal dialog to appear

Tags: jquery, events, triggers, click

This code works but the element with class "genbutton-delete" needs to be clicked twice to work. Can somebody help me please?

```
$(document).ready(function(){                                                                                                                               
$(".genbutton-delete").click(function(){                                                                                                                
    var id = $(this).attr("id");                                                                                                                        
    $("#del-"+id+"").dialog("open");                                                                                                                    
    var dialogOpts = {                                                                                                                                  
        modal: true,                                                                                                                                    
        bgiframe: true,                                                                                                                                 
        autoOpen: false,                                                                                                                                
        width: 400,                                                                                                                                     
        buttons: {                                                                                                                                      
            "Delete": function() {                                                                                                                      
                $.ajax({                                                                                                                                
                    type: "post",                                                                                                                       
                    url: ""+siteURL+"/a/delete?media="+id+"",                                                                                           
                    data: "delete=1",                                                                                                                   
                    success: function(data) {location.href="?delete=1";}                                                                                
                });                                                                                                                                     
            },                                                                                                                                          
            "Cancel": function() {$(this).dialog("close");}                                                                                             
        },                                                                                                                                              
        open: function() {                                                                                                                              
            $("#del-"+id+"").load(""+siteURL+"/a/delete?media="+id+"");                                                                                 
            $("#loader-"+id+"").show();                                                                                                                 
        }                                                                                                                                               
    };                                                                                                                                                  
    $("#del-"+id+"").dialog(dialogOpts);                                                                                                                
    return false;                                                                                                                                       
});
```

});

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You try to open the dialog before initializing it !

First click, you dialog gets initialized.

```
$("#del-"+id+"").dialog("open"); // does nothing
// init the dialog but does not open because autoOpen: false
$("#del-"+id+"").dialog(dialogOpts);
```

Second click it is finally opened.

---

**Either**, move the call to method "open" after the init and before the `return false;`

```
$("#del-"+id+"").dialog(dialogOpts);
$("#del-"+id+"").dialog("open");
return false;
```

**Or** change the option `autoOpen` to true and remove the "open" method call

```
//$("#del-"+id+"").dialog("open");                                                                                                                    
var dialogOpts = {                                                                                                                                  
    ...                                                                                                                               
    autoOpen: true,                                                                                                                                
    ...                                                                                                                                               
};                                                                                                                                                  
$("#del-"+id+"").dialog(dialogOpts);
```

Comment: OMG! I'm such a noob!!  Thanks @didier-ghys

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're calling dialog("open") before your dialog is all setup. Thus you have to click the button again to get it to open.

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){                                                                                                                               
$(".genbutton-delete").click(function(){                                                                                                                
    var id = $(this).attr("id");                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    var dialogOpts = {                                                                                                                                  
        modal: true,                                                                                                                                    
        bgiframe: true,                                                                                                                                 
        autoOpen: false,                                                                                                                                
        width: 400,                                                                                                                                     
        buttons: {                                                                                                                                      
            "Delete": function() {                                                                                                                      
                $.ajax({                                                                                                                                
                    type: "post",                                                                                                                       
                    url: ""+siteURL+"/a/delete?media="+id+"",                                                                                           
                    data: "delete=1",                                                                                                                   
                    success: function(data) {location.href="?delete=1";}                                                                                
                });                                                                                                                                     
            },                                                                                                                                          
            "Cancel": function() {$(this).dialog("close");}                                                                                             
        },                                                                                                                                              
        open: function() {                                                                                                                              
            $("#del-"+id+"").load(""+siteURL+"/a/delete?media="+id+"");                                                                                 
            $("#loader-"+id+"").show();                                                                                                                 
        }                                                                                                                                               
    };                                                                                                                                                  
    $("#del-"+id+"").dialog(dialogOpts);      
    $("#del-"+id+"").dialog("open");  
    return false;                                                                                                                                       
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct but from your code I can see there is no need to initialize and show it seperately, specially if you are using a recent version of jQuery-UI then you wont even need to worry about opening or closing it to reuse the same element for a dialog.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){                                                                                                                               
      $(".genbutton-delete").click(function(){                                                                                                                
        var id = $(this).attr("id");                                                                                                                        
        $("#del-"+id+"").dialog({                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
            modal: true,                                                                                                                                    
            bgiframe: true,                                                                                                                                 
            autoOpen: true,                                                                                                                                
            width: 400,                                                                                                                                     
            buttons: {                                                                                                                                      
                "Delete": function() {                                                                                                                      
                    $.ajax({                                                                                                                                
                        type: "post",                                                                                                                       
                        url: ""+siteURL+"/a/delete?media="+id+"",                                                                                           
                        data: "delete=1",                                                                                                                   
                        success: function(data) {location.href="?delete=1";}                                                                                
                    });                                                                                                                                     
                },                                                                                                                                          
                "Cancel": function() {$(this).dialog("close");}                                                                                             
            },                                                                                                                                              
            open: function() {                                                                                                                              
                $("#del-"+id+"").load(""+siteURL+"/a/delete?media="+id+"");                                                                                 
                $("#loader-"+id+"").show();                                                                                                                 
            }                                                                                                                                               
        });                                                                                                                                                  
        return false;                                                                                                                                       
      });                                                                                                                                                     
    });
```

Comment: Because of `autoOpen: false` the dialog won't open by itself.

Comment: @ Didier Ghys tnx for pointing that out, I copied and pasted it!